# Помогите оптимизировать код

Tags: c++, оптимизация

В задаче на вход программе дается количество невыполненных заданий и время, которого не хватает на решение этих заданий.

Далее во второй строке дается время на выполнение каждой задачи

В третей строке баллы за эту задачу.

Нужно посчитать минимальное суммарное количество баллов, которые придется потерять.

Мой код работает идеально, но не проходит по времени данный тест. Ограничение 2 секунды.

```
   25 10
   1 2 5 9 18 26 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4098 8200 16400 32800 65900 122000 244000 488000 1000000     2000000 4000000 8000000
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Вот сам код:

Comment: вы сложность алгоритма оценить можете? И да, ровно эта задача уже была. Правильное решение - писать задачу о рюкзаке динамикой.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660955/Как-упростить-код-сократить-время-работы?noredirect=1#comment952754_660955 для тех кто видит)

Comment: @pavel это была моя задача, немного поменяла код. Но вот с задачей о рюкзаке возникли проблемы.

Comment: так и пишите в чём проблема. Уберите весь этот код, покажите вашу попытку) потому что правильный ответ на то что есть - удалить и писать с нуля другой алгоритм.

Comment: Не поняла суть задачи о рюкзаке. Как её применить к данной задаче

Comment: странный вопрос. Прямо по определению. У вас есть рюкзак (время) и вам надо впихать в него вещей с минимальной ценой.  Задача полностью совпадает со стандартной.

Comment: Там надо чтобы время было больше или равно. То есть рюкзак при необходимости можно переполнить

Comment: полностью условие задачи с ограничениями. Что тут будет рюкзак это факт, что можно переполнить - решается одной проверкой. Если миллион и скажем тысяча задач то можно пробовать.

Comment: Все равно не могу понять, как сделать.

Comment: у меня чуть оффтоп конечно вопрос. А зачем вы эти задачи решаете?

Comment: Прохожу курс по программированию. Там эти задачи.

Comment: @pavel у вас есть исходный код задачи о рюкзаке с динамикой?

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Задача_о_рюкзаке

Comment: @pavel а рабочий код есть?